# WPF - WinForms ReportViewer Not Displaying RDLC on RadWindow / Telerik Containers

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, telerik, rdlc

i am trying to display an rdlc report on a radwindow. but its not displaying. but if i use a normal window/page, it displays without any issues.

even loaded the content into a frame. but did not work.

is there any way around to display report viewer on Telerik RadWindow.

Thanks in advance,
Sarathi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. actually the rdlc report is rendering in the background.
but the WindowsFormsHost - used to display the rdlc, not displayed in the RadWindow / RadPane of Telerik. the issue is with the WindowsFormsHost.

but it can be displayed on Normal WPF Window using Windows Forms Host.
reference 
[Windows Forms Host in RadPane/RadWindow](https://www.telerik.com/forums/windowsformshost-in-radwindow)